# How to add overflow : hidden and max widths on images

Tags: html, css, image, overflow

I am trying to achieve a slider magazine type layout where the middle container displays the whole picture and the containers  to the left and right only show a snippet,  (20% of the image.)

I need the left and right container images to remain their height, same as middle image but only show 20% of the image.

How can I achieve this using html and css?

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ4K9/) to explain my working,

Please update the fiddle.

Thanks for all your help.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 image-container">
             <div class="left">
                 <a href="#"><img src="http://www.paulobriendesign.com/img/cover1.jpg" alt="Cover 1"></a>
             </div>
            <div class="center">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.paulobriendesign.com/img/cover1.jpg" alt="Cover 1"></a>
             </div>
            <div class="right">
                     <a href="#"><img src="http://www.paulobriendesign.com/img/cover1.jpg" alt="Cover 1"></a>
             </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to the end of your css rules:

```
.left, .right {
  overflow: hidden;  
}
.left img, .right img {
    width: 300%;
}
.right img {
    position: relative;
  right: 200%;  
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/QDWqH/)**

Comment: Thanks for you help :) Are you available for any freelance work? If so could I get your email address. It would be great to work with you